# Excel Vlookup calculating marks with age range and pushup result

Tags: excel, range, vlookup

I am testing my clients for pushups and other exercises. 
I want to make excel table where I can put client name, age, number of reps
and to make some formula that can put the new column with given mark. According to 
table of ranges.

**Table of problem**

[image]

Comment: can we assume possibility of redesign of input table you attached? In current view it's rather not possible to got result you need with formulas only.

Comment: It is possible to redesign table, I will adjust how it's suppose to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

As stated, change your Age and number of pushups to just the minimums; 20,30,40,50.  And change the order from lowest mark to highest.

And do not skip any lines.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D11,INDEX($A:$F,0,MATCH($C11,$1:$1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx, it help me a lot! How to do for multiple clients? For example, A column is name, B is age, C pushups, D mark for pushups? I guess i have to put range table somewhere ?

Comment: You would change the references I3 and I2 to the cells that have their information.

Comment: It doesnt want to show next 10 results.=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($I$3:$I$10,INDEX($A:$F,0,MATCH($H$3:$H$10,1:1))))

Comment: I would need to see how you set up the output search, to help.

Comment: See table3 down there.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your values, just write your minimum values in the cells (e.g. 20 instead of 20-29) and turn the table around so that 1 is on top and 5 is at the bottom. Then you can use the following formula:

```
=Indirect(Address(Match(val, Indirect(Address(4, Match(age, A2:F2, 1)) & ":" 
                                    & Address(8, Match(age, A2:F2, 1))), 1) + 3, 1))
```

Quite some formula actually ;) What it does:

```
Match(age, A2:F2, 1)
```

returns the column in which the user is to be sorted.

The inner Indirect creates a matrix with that column (e.g. if age is 25, this returns B4:B8).

The outter Match searches the value within this matrix and returns the corresponding row.

With that row and the fixed first column you can get your desired mark.

Comment: FWIW:  Both Indirect and Address are volatile functions(they will recalculate every time excel recalculates regardless if the underlying data changed or not).  These functions, though helpful and needed at time, should be avoided if other functions like INDEX can do the job.  INDEX only recalculates when the underlying data changes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D$11:$D$17,INDEX($A:$F,0,MATCH($C​$11:$C$17,1:1))))

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPXex.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thing,
if I want to be able to keep formula open for more people...formula remain the same,just to change D number and C number?

[table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyS4p.png)